# toLocaleDateString doesn't work with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```js
function formatDate(lang: string, date: Date) {
  const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
  return date.toLocaleDateString(lang, options);
}
```

and it throws this type error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(locales?: LocalesArgument, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ year: string; month: string; day: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.
      Types of property 'year' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"numeric" | "2-digit"'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(locales?: string | string[], options?: DateTimeFormatOptions): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ year: string; month: string; day: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.
```

I've tried to use:

```js
const options: DateTimeFormatOptions = { ... }
```

But TypeScript says that `DateTimeFormatOptions` is not defined.

I've fixed the issue by adding missing type:

```js
type DateTimeFormatOptions = {
  year: 'numeric';
  month: 'short';
  day: 'numeric'
};
```

But why is it needed; why can't TypeScript figure out that `year` (and other properties) is given literal type and not a string?

Comment: Just inline it, `date.toLocaleDateString(lang, { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' });`, so a narrower type can be inferred. Or make the options object `as const`. The inferred type is `{ ..., day: string }`, and most strings are **not** `"numeric"` or `"2-digit"`. And the type is `Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions`, it's not global: https://tsplay.dev/WKXQZw.